# Indirect Function to Build Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I am trying to use the indirect function in Excel to build a formula to return a value on another sheet.

On Sheet A cell D3 has the value B

I want to use the value B to return a value from cell B6 in a Sheet called App Summary.

I tired the below formula on Sheet A:

="'App Summary'!"&Indirect("D3") & 6

This return the string 'App Summary'!B6.

How do I get it to calculate so that is returns the value in cell B6 from the App Summary Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually put the whole statement in the `Indirect()` function and use '&' to connect parts that are direct quotes with parts that are dynamic.

Example: `=INDIRECT("'Workbook A'!A"&A1)` will return the value in `'Workbook A'!` that is located in column A, at the row indicated by the number in the current sheet's A1.  If A1 is 1, this will return the value in `'Workbook A'!A1`.

You might try `=Indirect("'App Summary'!"&D3&"6")`.  I'm assuming you want to use a column from another sheet who's value is stored in D3 of the current sheet and look in the 6th row on the Summary sheet.

Comment: You might just need to remove your quotes to make this work.